# Is there a better way cancel the current request and redirect to an error page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, error-handling, controller

Frequently when I'm dealing with controllers I have found the need to stop the current action and then show an error page. Currently I have a method to show my error page in application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def show_error msg
    render file: 'public/404.html', message: msg, layout: false
  end

end
```

And then from another controller I can use it like this:

```
class BikesController < ApplicationController 

  def inspect 
    @bike = Bikes.find(params[:id])
    show_error("You can't inspect a bike without wheels!") and return unless @bike.hasWheels?       
    @similar_bikes = Bikes.similar_to(@bike)
    render "inspect"
  end

end
```

However I dislike having to include `and return` alongside my `show_error` method to ensure that nothing else is executed. Is there a cleaner way to do this without using `return`?

Comment: no, return is why it works. render doesn't explicitly return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails-way of handling situations like that is throwing an exception and handling it.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class NotFoundError < StandardError; end

  rescue_from NotFoundError do |e|
    render file: "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", message: e.message, layout: false, status: :not_found
  end

  ...
end
```

`raise NotFoundError, msg` in any action of `ApplicationController` or its child stops the action and renders your `404.html` file, returning HTTP Error 404.